# Adding sql data into a tabel with html and php

Tags: php, html, sql

When it displays in my table now, it echos the align center into the table with my data. How do I get rid of this

```
<?php
                mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); //connect to server
                mysqli_select_db("first_ db") or die("Can not connect to database");
                $query = mysqli_query("Select * from volunteer");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo '<td> align="center">'. $row['StaffID']."</td>";
                        echo '<td> align="center">'. $row['Name']."</td>";
                        echo '<td> align="center">'. $row['Address']."</td>";
                        echo '<td> align="center">'. $row['PhoneNumber']."</td>";
                        echo '<td> align="center">'. $row['Gender']."</td>";
                        echo '<td> align="center">'. $row['StaffStatus']."</td>";
                        echo '<td> align="center"><a hred="Edit.php">Edit</a> </td>'
                        echo '<td> align="center"><a href="Delete.php">Delete</a> </td>';
                        echo "</tr>";
                }
?>      


            </table>
        </body>     
</html>
```

Comment: You mention that you get a bunch of errors. What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: A lot of syntax error in your code. First of all, replace `Print` for `print` or `echo`, after fix the `$row['StaffID]`and `$row['/PhoneNumber']`. Hmmm, and "Edit" td line is missing `;`

Comment: I now get this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\staff.php on line 42

Comment: because you did not close the first echo

Comment: close this `echo '<td> align="center"><a hred="Edit.php">Edit</a> </td>'`  semi colon is missing

Comment: Any idea why it wouldn't connect to my db?

Comment: `$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}`

Comment: @JamesMorris is your database `first_ db`  or `first_db`?

Comment: All works now thanks, just wondering how to remove the align center from the table, because now it shows my values from my db but also shows align center in the box

Comment: @JamesMorris check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to always put your session before any other code

Second

```
  mysql_connect
  mysql_query 
  mysql_select_db
  mysql_fetch_array
```

has been deprecated use

```
 mysqli_connect     
 mysqli_query
 mysqli_select_db
 mysqli_fetch_array
```

Third your table does no have a

```
tbody or thead
```

Replace print with echo

Answer (score 0):

this thing of you mixing double and single quotes at the same times is the problem.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "username";
$password   = "";
$dbname     = "first_db";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$sql   = "Select * from volunteer";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td> align=\"center\">" . $row['StaffID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> align=\"center\">" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> align=\"center\">" . $row['Address'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> align=\"center\">" . $row['PhoneNumber'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> align=\"center\">" . $row['Gender'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> align=\"center\">" . $row['StaffStatus'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> align=\"center\"><a hred=\"Edit.php?id=" . $row['StaffID'] . "\">Edit</a> </td>";
        echo "<td> align=\"center\"><a href=\"Delete.php?id=" . $row['StaffID'] . "\">Delete</a> </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

} else {

    echo "no results";
}

?>      


            </table>
        </body>     
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

replace `Print` with `echo`

```
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo '<td> align="center">'. $row['StaffID]."</td>";
                    echo '<td> align="center">'. $row['Name']."</td>";
                    echo '<td> align="center">'. $row['Address']."</td>";
                    echo '<td> align="center">'. $row['/PhoneNumber']."</td>";
                    echo '<td> align="center">'. $row['Gender']."</td>";
                    echo '<td> align="center">'. $row['StaffStatus']."</td>";
                    echo '<td> align="center"><a hred="Edit.php">Edit</a> </td>'
                    echo '<td> align="center"><a href="Delete.php">Delete</a> </td>';
                    echo "</tr>";
```